# Taking screenshot via button in ionic/cordova using screenshot plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want my ionic project to take a screenshot and store it in camera roll.
currently the button is not able to take any screenshot. I am testing the app on an android device.
I am using this plugin: https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-view>
      <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ng-click="$cordovaScreenshot.capture()">screenshot</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
.service('$cordovaScreenshot', ['$q', function($q) {
    return {
        capture: function(filename, extension, quality) {
        filename = filename || 'pic';
            extension = extension || 'jpg';
            quality = quality || '100';

            var defer = $q.defer();

            navigator.screenshot.save(function(error, res) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    defer.reject(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('screenshot saved in: ', res.filePath);
                    defer.resolve(res.filePath);
                }
            }, extension, quality, filename);

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I think you need a controller between your view (html) and your angular service. Rest seems to be okay, it's just that ng-click can not directly run the capture() method on a service.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense.Can you please elaborate the contents of the controller that I should add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was rectified.
The code can be found at

https://github.com/manik1596/coredovaScreenshotShare

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-up on my first comment. I think you need a controller between the view (HTML) and your Angular service. A HTML view can't directly communicate with a service, so we need a intermediate controller.

Something along the lines of:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
.controller('myController', ['$cordovaScreenshot', function($cordovaScreenshot) {
    $scope.captureScreenshot = function() {
        $cordovaScreenshot.capture('filename', 'png', 100).then(function(result) {
            // do something with result
        }, function(error) {
            // do something with error
        });
    };
}]);
```

As you can see, we're using dependency injection to inject the `$cordovaScreenshot` service.

And your view will trigger the captureScreenshot method:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="myController">
    <button class="button" ng-click="captureScreenshot()">screenshot</button>
</ion-content>
```

Notice the `ng-controller` and a change in the `ng-click` method.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can provide you with more info. What is going wrong? Do you see any errors in developer tools console?